# Can multiple dispatch be achieved in Haskell with pattern matching on type classes?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typeclass

This is a question about [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch) in Haskell.

Below I use the term "compliant to [type class]" to mean "has type which is instance of [type class]", because type classes are often like interfaces, so it's intuitive to think of a concrete thing like an actual Int value as being "compliant" to an interface/type class by virtue of its type implementing whatever is needed to belong to that interface/type class.

Consider the example of wanting to make a single exponentiation function that will work whether it is called with `Floating` arguments, `Num`, `Integral` or whatever, and it works by using the type classes that are implemented by the types of the arguments to select a pre-existing exponentiation function to call.

The function `(^)` has type `(^) :: (Integral b, Num a) => a -> b -> a` and the function `(**)` has type `(**) :: Floating a => a -> a -> a`.

Suppose I want to create a function `my_pow` that accepts a `Num` compliant first argument and a `Num` compliant second argument.

If both arguments are `Floating` compliant, then it will call `(**)`; if the second argument is merely `Integral` compliant, it will call `(^)`; and any other case will give a pattern matching error.

My naive first try was to treat the type classes like value constructors and try to pattern match within the function definition:

```
my_pow :: (Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> a
my_pow (Floating x) (Floating y) = x ** y
my_pow x (Integral y) = x ^ y
```

but this gives the errors:

```
tmp.hs:25:6: Not in scope: data constructor `Floating'

tmp.hs:25:19: Not in scope: data constructor `Floating'

tmp.hs:26:8: Not in scope: data constructor `Integral'
```

probably meaning that I cannot treat type classes as value constructors, which is not surprising.

But then Googling around for how to pattern-match against particular type class properties of the arguments that are more specific than the type class constraints in the function definition did not yield any clear answers.

What is the preferred way to make this sort of polymorphism -- effectively a dispatch pattern where the function has relaxed type class constraints overall, but then is defined by pattern matching on more specific type class constraints for any of the cases it will dispatch to other other functions.

Comment: This isn't really possible.  For one thing, what if I make a type (incorrectly, but that's not the point) that implements both `Floating` and `Integral`?  How would the compiler know which to use?  This is particularly the case if I implemented `(^)` and `(**)` to have different behavior.  While this makes no sense from a mathematical point of view, in general this can be something that happens within an application with typeclasses.

Comment: The answer seems obvious to me: it will detect the first matching pattern and execute that one, and it is the programmer's responsibility to know how that will work with the type classes involved. If the programmer relies on two incompatible type classes that can be mixed, then an error would be the correct output, and the patterns would be changed to reflect the precedence of pattern matching that is desired. I have an example where the two patterns are not mutually exclusive and the first one is selected, but it's too big for a comment.

Comment: I'm also surprised there isn't a way to put an ordering on the type classes themselves, so that in the case of number types, for example, there would be a hierarchy from Int to SignedInt to Rational to Real (Floating, possibly ordered on precision) to Complex, and that Num meant you are at least compliant with one of them, and that being compliant with one means you are compliant with any predecessors as well. But I can see how that abstraction might not be desirable in the context of programming where you want types to embody non-math things as well.

Comment: Being a `Num` does not make you a `Floating`.  Being a `Floating` makes you a `Num`.  There is a hierarchy, it just goes from most general to most specific, and only with type classes.  There is no direct type inheritance in Haskell, so you can't say that an `Int` is also a `Float`, even though there is a lossless conversion from `Int` to `Float`.  Instead, you can convert an `Int` to a `Num a => a`, and since `Float` is an instance of that it can be substituted in as being more specific.

Comment: I don't think anything I wrote contradicted your first sentence. I only need `Num` because it means "you are compliant to possibly one or more of some other bunch of type classes, or just Num", which is all I need. Then, I need to check which of those others it is compliant to, and do different handling, in an order I choose, based on that.

Comment: Also, what you're really wanting is multiple dispatch on type classes, Haskell does not have that, sorry.  And I can definitely think of more complicated cases where having these constructs would lead to ambiguous programs.  What if my function to overload performs IO, and one implementation launches missiles and the other implementation releases a swarm of adorable kittens?  It would be a dangerous program if you have to hope that the patterns are matched in just the right way so that you don't accidentally start WW3 instead of releasing a wave of cute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62839/discussion-between-bheklilr-and-ems).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The normal way to "pattern match" on types in the way you're describing is with type class instances. With concrete types, this is easy using `MultiParamTypeClasses`; this is how Haskell implements multiple dispatch.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
module SO26303353 where

class (Num a, Num b) => Power a b where
  my_pow :: a -> b -> a

instance Power Double Double where
  my_pow = (**)

instance Num a => Power a Integer where
  my_pow = (^)
```

This works just fine. It's more or less idiomatic Haskell, except that `(**)` and `(^)` are different operations and some people might object to blurring the distinction.

You're asking for something a bit more elaborate, however. You want multiple dispatch not only on *types* but on *classes of types*. This is a significantly different and more powerful thing. In particular, it would work for *all* types that could have instances of `Floating` or `Intergral`, even types that haven't been written yet! Here's how it would be written ideally:

```
instance (Floating a) => Power a a where
  my_pow = (**)

instance (Num a, Integral b) => Power a b where
  my_pow = (^)
```

**This doesn't work**, though, because the constraint solver does not backtrack, and does not consider instance constraints when choosing an instance. So `my_pow` doesn't work, for instance, with two `Int`s:

```
ghci> :t my_pow :: Int -> Int -> Int
No instance for (Floating Int)
```

This happens because the "more specific" `Power a a` instance matches, because the two types are equal. GHC then imposes the `Floating` constraint on `a`, and barfs when it can't satisfy it. It does not then backtrack and try the `Power a b` instance.

It may or may not be possible to hack around the limitation using advanced type system features, but I don't think you could ever make a drop-in replacement for both `(**)` and `(^)` in current Haskell.

### Edit: general comments

(Note that we're kind of straying away from a Q&A format here.)

In rereading your question and comment, I notice you're using the term "dispatch" in a way I'm not familiar with. A quick Google turns up articles on [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) and the [visitor design pattern](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/visitor/java/2). Is that where you're coming from? They look a bit like what you're trying to do--write a function that does totally different things based on the types of its arguments. I want to add a few things to this answer that may help hone your sense of idiomatic Haskell. (Or may just be disjointed rambling.)

Haskell normally disregards the idea of a "runtime type". Even in @Cirdec's more elaborate answer, all the types are statically known, "at compile time." (Using the REPL, `ghci`, doesn't change things, except that "compile time" gets kind of hazy.) In fact, intuitions about what happen "at runtime" are often different in Haskell than other languages, not least because GHC performs aggressive optimizations.

Idiomatic Haskell is built on a foundation of [parametric polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism); a function like `replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]` works absolutely the same for *any* type `a`. As a result, we know a lot about what `replicate` does without having to look at its implementation. This attitude is really helpful, and it deeply infects the brains of Haskell programmers. You'll notice that me and many other Haskell programmers go crazy with type annotations, especially in a forum like this one. The static types are very meaningful. (Keyword: free theorems.) (This isn't immediately relevant to your question.)

Haskell uses type classes to permit [ad hoc polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ad_hoc_polymorphism). In my mind, 'ad hoc' refers to the fact that the *implementation* of a function may be different for different types. This is of course critical for numerical types, and has been applied over the years in countless ways. But it's important to understand that everything is still statically typed, even with type classes. To actually evaluate any type-class function--to get a value out of it--you need to in the end choose a specific type. (With numeric types, the defaulting rules frequently choose it for you.) You can of course combine things to produce another polymorphic function (or value).

Historically, type classes were thought of strictly as a mechanism for function overloading, in the sense of having the same *name* for several *distinct functions*. In other words, rather than `addInt :: Int -> Int -> Int`, `addFloat :: Float -> Float -> Float`, we have one name: `(+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a`. But it's still fundamentally the same idea: there are a bunch of completely different functions called `(+)`. (Now we tend to talk about type classes in terms of "laws," but that's a different topic.) There's oftentimes *no* literal dispatch occurring with a function like `(+)`, or even non-primitive functions.

Yes, type classes are a bit like interfaces, but don't allow an OOP mindset to creep in too far. If you are writing a function with a type like `Num a => a -> a`, the expectation is that the *only* thing you know about `a` is that it is an instance of `Num`. You can't look behind the curtain, as it were. (Without cheating. Which is hard.) The only way to manipulate values of type `a` is with fully polymorphic functions and with other `Num` functions. In particular, you can't determine whether `a` is also an instance of some other class.

The various compiler extensions we've been playing with blur this model a bit, because we now can write, essentially, *type level functions*. But don't confuse that with dynamic dispatch.

Oh, by the way, Haskell does support dynamic types. See [`Data.Dymamic`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-Dynamic.html). To be honest, I've never really seen much use for it outside of interop with other languages. (I'm willing to be wrong.) The typical "visitor pattern" problems can be implemented in other ways.

Comment: What is the preferred alternative to a dispatch pattern then? To create a wholly new data type whose value constructors encode the type info? Like `data MyNum = MadeWithFloating Float | MadeWithIntegral Int` and then do pattern matching on these value constructors? This seems even more anti Haskell to me than being able to pattern match on type classes and allow the programmer to possibly make mistakes due to overlap when doing so and simple live with handling errors.

Answer (score 5):

Like [Christian Conkle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26305824/414413) hinted at, we can determine if a type has an `Integral` or `Floating` instance using more advanced type system features. We will try to determine if the second argument has an `Integral` instance. Along the way we will use a host of language extensions, and still fall a bit short of our goal. I'll introduce the following language extensions where they are used

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyDataDecls #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
```

#### Convert Integral context to type

To begin with we will make a class that will try to capture information from the context of a type (whether there's an `Integral` instance) and convert it into a type which we can match on. This requires the `FunctionalDependencies` extension to say that the `flag` can be uniquely determined from the type `a`. It also requires `MultiParamTypeClasses`.

```
class IsIntegral a flag | a -> flag
```

We'll make two types to use for the `flag` type to represent when a type does (`HTrue`) or doesn't (`HFalse`) have an `Integral` instance. This uses the `EmptyDataDecls` extension.

```
data HTrue
data HFalse
```

We'll provide a default - when there isn't an `IsIntegral` instance for `a` that forces `flag` to be something other than `HFalse` we provide an instance that says it's `HFalse`. This requires the `TypeFamilies`, `FlexibleInstances`, and `UndecidableInstances` extensions.

```
instance (flag ~ HFalse) => IsIntegral a flag
```

What we'd really like to do is say that every `a` with an `Integral a` instance has an `IsIntegral a HTrue` instance. Unfortunately, if we add an `instance (Integral a) => IsIntegral a HTrue` instance we will be in the same situation Christian described. This second instance will be used by preference, and when the `Integral` constraint is encountered it will be added to the context with no backtracking. Instead we will need to list all the `Integral` types ourselves. This is where we fall short of our goal. (I'm skipping the [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Prelude.html#t:Integral) `Integral` types from `System.Posix.Types` since they aren't defined equally on all platforms).

```
import Data.Int
import Data.Word
import Foreign.C.Types
import Foreign.Ptr

instance IsIntegral Int HTrue
instance IsIntegral Int8 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Int16 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Int32 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Int64 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Integer HTrue
instance IsIntegral Word HTrue
instance IsIntegral Word8 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Word16 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Word32 HTrue
instance IsIntegral Word64 HTrue
instance IsIntegral CUIntMax HTrue
instance IsIntegral CIntMax HTrue
instance IsIntegral CUIntPtr HTrue
instance IsIntegral CIntPtr HTrue
instance IsIntegral CSigAtomic HTrue
instance IsIntegral CWchar HTrue
instance IsIntegral CSize HTrue
instance IsIntegral CPtrdiff HTrue
instance IsIntegral CULLong HTrue
instance IsIntegral CLLong HTrue
instance IsIntegral CULong HTrue
instance IsIntegral CLong HTrue
instance IsIntegral CUInt HTrue
instance IsIntegral CInt HTrue
instance IsIntegral CUShort HTrue
instance IsIntegral CShort HTrue
instance IsIntegral CUChar HTrue
instance IsIntegral CSChar HTrue
instance IsIntegral CChar HTrue
instance IsIntegral IntPtr HTrue
instance IsIntegral WordPtr HTrue
```

#### Matching on IsIntegral

Our end goal is to be able to provide appropriate instances for the following class

```
class (Num a, Num b) => Power a b where
    pow :: a -> b -> a
```

We want to match on types to choose which code to use. We'll make a class with an extra type to hold the flag for whether `b` is an `Integral` type. The extra argument to `pow'` lets type inference choose the correct `pow'` to use.

```
class (Num a, Num b) => Power' flag a b where
    pow' :: flag -> a -> b -> a
```

Now we'll write two instances, one for when `b` is `Integral` and one for when it isn't. When `b` isn't `Integral`, we can only provide an instance when `a` and `b` are the same.

```
instance (Num a, Integral b) => Power' HTrue a b where
    pow' _ = (^)

instance (Floating a, a ~ b) => Power' HFalse a b where
    pow' _ = (**)
```

Now, whenever we can determine if `b` is `Integral` with `IsIntegral` and can provide a `Power'` instance for that result, we can provide the `Power` instance which was our goal. This requires the `ScopedTypeVariables` extension to get the correct type for the extra argument to `pow'`

```
instance (IsIntegral b flag, Power' flag a b) => Power a b where
    pow = pow' (undefined::flag)
```

Actually using these definitions requires the `OverlappingInstances` extension.

```
main = do
    print (pow 7 (7 :: Int))
    print (pow 8.3 (7 :: Int))
    print (pow 1.2 (1.2 :: Double))
    print (pow 7 (7 :: Double))
```

You can read another explanation of how to use `FunctionalDependencies` or `TypeFamilies` to avoid overlap in overlapping instances in the [Advanced Overlap](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) article on HaskellWiki.

Comment: @Christian Conkle The article about this is AdvancedOverlap on HaskellWiki: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap