# Overlapping instances error when trying to write fallback instance

Tags: haskell, typeclass, functional-dependencies, type-families, overlapping-instances

I'm trying to do something similar to the [advanced overlap](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/AdvancedOverlap) trick to define an instance with overlapping behavior. I'm trying to derive an instance for a tuple that will use an instance for the `fst` field if one exists, otherwise use the instance for the `snd` field if it exists. This ultimately results in a seemingly incorrect error about overlapping instances.

To begin with, I'm using all of the kitchen sink except for `OverlappingInstances`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
```

I'm also using a poly-kinded `Proxy` and type level or, `:||:`.

```
import Data.Proxy

type family (:||:) (a :: Bool) (b :: Bool) :: Bool
type instance (:||:) False a = a
type instance (:||:) True a = True
```

`A` is a very simple class to play with. `ThingA` has an `A` instance; `ThingB` doesn't.

```
class A x where
    traceA :: x -> String

data ThingA = ThingA
data ThingB = ThingB

instance A ThingA where
    traceA = const "ThingA"
```

The goal of the next parts is to write an `A` instance for `(x, y)` which will be defined as long as there's either an `A x` or `A y` instance. If there's an `A x` instance, it will return `("fst " ++) . traceA . fst`. If there is **not** an `A x` instance but there is a `B x` instance it will return `("snd " ++) . traceA . fst`.

The first step will be to make a functional dependency to test for whether there's an `A` instance by matching against the instance head. This is the ordinary approach from the advanced overlap article.

```
class APred (flag :: Bool) x | x -> flag

instance APred 'True ThingA
instance (flag ~ 'False) => APred flag x
```

If we can determine if `x` and `y` both have `A` instances, we can determine if `(x, y)` is going to have one.

```
instance (APred xflag x, APred yflag y, t ~ (xflag :||: yflag)) => APred t (x, y)
```

Now I'm going to depart from the simple example in advanced overlap and introduce a second functional dependency to select whether to use the `A x` or `A y` instance. (We could use a different kind than `Bool` for `Chooses` and `SwitchA` to avoid confusion with `APred`.)

```
class Chooses (flag :: Bool) x | x -> flag
```

If there's an `A x` instance we'll always choose `'True`, otherwise `'False`.

```
instance (APred 'True x) => Chooses 'True (x, y) 
instance (flag ~ 'False) => Chooses flag (x, y)
```

Then, like the advanced overlap example, I define a class identical to `A` except with an extra type variable for the choice and a `Proxy` argument for every member.

```
class SwitchA (flag :: Bool) x where
    switchA :: Proxy flag -> x -> String
```

This is easy to define instances for

```
instance (A x) => SwitchA 'True (x, y) where
    switchA _ = ("fst " ++) . traceA . fst

instance (A y) => SwitchA 'False (x, y) where
    switchA _ = ("snd " ++) . traceA . snd
```

Finally, if there is a `SwitchA` instance for the same type that `(x, y)` `Chooses`, we can define an `A (x, y)` instance.

```
instance (Chooses flag (x, y), SwitchA flag (x, y)) => A (x, y) where
    traceA = switchA (Proxy :: Proxy flag)
```

Everything up to here compiles beautifully. However, if I try to add

```
traceA (ThingA, ThingB)
```

I get the following error.

```
    Overlapping instances for Chooses 'True (ThingA, ThingB)
      arising from a use of `traceA'
    Matching instances:
      instance APred 'True x => Chooses 'True (x, y)
        -- Defined at defaultOverlap.hs:46:10
      instance flag ~ 'False => Chooses flag (x, y)
        -- Defined at defaultOverlap.hs:47:10
    In the first argument of `print', namely
      `(traceA (ThingA, ThingA))'
```

What's going on here? Why do these instances overlap when looking for an instance for `Chooses 'True ...`; shouldn't the `instance flag ~ 'False => Chooses flag ...` instance fail to match when `flag` is already known to be `'True`?

Conversely, if I try

```
traceA (ThingB, ThingA)
```

I get the error

```
    No instance for (A ThingB) arising from a use of `traceA'
    In the first argument of `print', namely
      `(traceA (ThingB, ThingA))'
```

Any insight into what is going on when I try to push the compiler into doing what it's designed not to do would be helpful.

#### Edit - Simplification

Based on an observation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27454546/414413), we can get rid of `Chooses` completely and write

```
instance (APred choice x, SwitchA choice (x, y)) => A (x, y) where
    traceA = switchA (Proxy :: Proxy choice)
```

This solves the problem for `traceA (ThingB, ThingA)`

Comment: With both the simplification and `OverlappingInstances` this works for all my test cases. I don't remember `OverlappingInstances` being required for advanced overlap, but even my own older answer disagrees with me. http://stackoverflow.com/a/26307385/414413

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see what is really going on, look at the `Chooses` class. Specifically, notice that it is not lazy in the `False` case (ie, when it cannot immediately determine it should have value true):

```
chooses :: Chooses b x =>  x -> Proxy b 
chooses _ = Proxy

>:t chooses (ThingA, ())
chooses (ThingA, ()) :: Proxy 'True
>:t chooses (ThingB, ())

<interactive>:1:1: Warning:
    Couldn't match type 'True with 'False
    In the expression: chooses (ThingB, ())
```

The reason *why* it isn't lazy isn't quite so simple. The most specific instance, which is

```
instance (APred 'True x) => Chooses 'True (x, y)
```

is tried first. To verify if this, the compiler must check the `APred`. Here, `instance APred 'True ThingA` does not match, because you have `ThingB`. So it falls through to the 2nd instance and unifies `flag` (in Chooses) with False. Then the constraint `APred 'True x` cannot hold! So typechecking fails. The type error you got is sort of strange, but I think that is because you don't have OverlappingInstances enabled. When I turn it on with your code, I get the following:

```
>traceA (ThingA, ThingA)
"fst ThingA"
>traceA (ThingB, ThingA)

<interactive>:43:1:
    Couldn't match type 'True with 'False
    In the expression: traceA (ThingB, ThingA)
    In an equation for `it': it = traceA (ThingB, ThingA)
```

Which is as expected - the types True and False cannot be unified.

The fix is quite simple. Convert your classes to type functions. Type functions are essentially equivalent, but "more lazy". This is very hand wavy - sorry I don't have a better explanation why it works.

```
type family APred' x :: Bool where 
  APred' ThingA = True
  APred' x = False 

type family Chooses' x :: Bool where 
  Chooses' (x, y) = APred' x 

instance (Chooses' (x,y) ~ flag, SwitchA flag (x, y)) => A (x, y) where
    traceA = switchA (Proxy :: Proxy flag)
```

Now you think "oh no, I have to rewrite all my code to use type families." That is not the case, since you can always "lower" a type family to a Class predicate with a functional dependency:

```
instance Chooses' x ~ b => Chooses b x
```

Now your original instance `instance (Chooses flag (x, y), SwitchA flag (x, y)) => A (x, y) where ...` will work as expected.

```
>traceA (ThingA, ThingA)
"fst ThingA"
>traceA (ThingB, ThingA)
"snd ThingA"
```

Comment: With type families, your answer relies on a closed type family for `APred'`. In an open type family, we can't have a corresponding `type instance APred' x = False`. What I'm trying to do (essentially default logic) requires `APred` to be open.

Comment: It seems like functional dependencies aren't very functional. I've been reading `| x -> b` as "given `x` we can find `b`", but the whole trick from advanced deriving is that the variable still appears in the head - probably because we can't figure out `b` from `x`, which is why the `A (x, y)` instance doesn't work. It can't figure out `flag` from `x` due to the functional dependency in the context. Functional dependencies seem to be saying something more relational, like, "given `C x b | x -> b` then `C x b2` implies `b2 ~ b`".

Comment: If `APred` must be open, replace your original Choose instances with `instance (APred flag x) => Chooses flag (x, y)`, and it will work (with OverlappingInstances).

Comment: I did that (actually simplified it to get rid of `Chooses` completely) and everything worked with `OverlappingInstances`. I forgot that advanced overlap still has overlapping instances at the use site.